# My prompt code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple JS calculator. However, the prompt within the variables aren't coming up. And yes, I will be changing the child functions into variables to make the switch statement possible. But even after punching it into JS fixers, it doesn't work. Can anyone advise me on what to do? I am kinda stuck here. I have tried putting it into JSFiddle but it still hasn't worked. Thanks if I get answered!

```
var firstNumber = prompt("Type in the first number that you want to add,subtract,divide,multiply,power(square or to the power of) or square root.");

    var operationForNumber() = prompt("Type in the symbol that matches the operation that you want to use(2 for square, ! for square root, /,for division and a * for multiplication).");

    var secondNumber() = prompt("Type in the second number that you want to add,subtract,divide,multiply,square or square root.");


    switch (operationForNumber) {
        case +:
            firstNumber "+"
            secondNumber
            break;
        case -:
            firstNumber "-"
            secondNumber
            break;
        case /:
        firstNumber "/"
        secondNumber
        case *:
            firstNumber "*"
            secondNumber
            break;
        case 2:
            Math.pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        case !:
            sqrt(firstNumber)
        default:
            console.log("The number you have typed is too great to be calculated or the operation that you chose(+,/,-,X) isn't valid!");
    }
```

Comment: Wrap your operators with quotes otherwise you have syntax errors

Comment: Operators as in +,- etc. ?

Comment: You need to run this in an environment where you see syntax errors because there are too many of them (missing variables, functions that don't exists, etc.)

Comment: `firstNumber`, `secondNumber` and `operationForNumber` are functions, they need to be called to get the value. And they need to `return` something, in order to return something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the results of your prompt calls in variables to make them usable for the statements inside the switch.

`var firstNumber = prompt("Type in the first number that you want to 
add,subtract,divide,multiply,power(square or to the power of) or square root.");
    var operationForNumber = prompt("Type in the symbol that matches the operation that you want to use(2 for square, ! for square root, /,for division and a * for multiplication).");
    var secondNumber = prompt("Type in the second number that you want to add, subtract, divide, multiply, square or square root.");`

Also please adhere to a consistent code style and terminate statements with semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing, because you don't have quotes around the operators in switch-cases. Do something like this for all the cases:

```
case "+":
case "-":
```

etc.

Comment: That's not the only problem, "sqrt" is also not defined, he's using operationForNumber as a variable even though it's a function, etc.

Comment: this.lau - I know about the function part. I have mentioned that above. I can fix that!